# Allow for a variable to affect number of statements in a loop

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any way to allow "testscore" variable to affect the number of statements in the do while loop? Like if say testscore = 4, I can have up to score4, and it will be included in the calculations.

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Task4 {
    public static void main(String[] arges) {

        double nof=1;
        double testscore;
        double score1;
        double score2;
        double score3;
        double averagescore;
        double x=11;
        String input;

        input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many students do you have?");
        nof = Double.parseDouble(input);

        input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many test scores per student?");
        testscore=Double.parseDouble(input);

        do {
          input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter score 1");
          score1= Double.parseDouble(input);

          input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter score 2");
          score2 = Double.parseDouble(input);

          input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter score 3");
          score3=Double.parseDouble(input);

          averagescore = (score1 + score2 + score3)/testscore;

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The student's average test score is " + averagescore);
          x++;

        } while (x <= nof);
    }
}
```

Comment: sure. You can use an array of scores instead of score1, score2, ... and iterate over the scores using testscore as end of loop

Comment: I'm so sorry but i'm very new to Java, could you explain more?

Comment: you create an array of ints with testscores as size. Then, you iterate over a loop, from 0 to (testscores - 1), and use that iteration's value (starting from 0) as index to store values in your array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a for loop to gather the scores. If you're only using the scores to compute the average then you can just keep a running total. If you need the scores for more than that you can create a `double[] scores = new double[testscores];` variable to store them in as they are read.

```java
public static void main(String[] arges) {

    int nof = 1; // this should be an int since you can't have a partial student
    int testscore;  // also an int since you can't have a partial test
    String input;

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many students do you have?");
    nof = Integer.parseInt(input);

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many test scores per student?");
    testscore = Integer.parseInt(input);

    for (int num = 1; num <= nof; num++) {
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < testscore; i++) {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Student #" + num + ": Enter score " + i);
            total += Double.parseDouble(input);
        }

        double averagescore = total / testscore;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student " + num + "'s average test score is " + averagescore);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, according to your code and comment, it's nof that should be an int. So ... first you recommend using an array, and then, in your example, you don't do that yourself?

Comment: You're right, both `nof` and `testscore` should be integers. I've updated the answer. I didn't recommend using an array unless you need to reference the individual scores later. It's not needed in the code example because they're just totalled to calculate an average. I didn't do it because it's not essential to answer the question that was asked.